# Alternative code for Array.push() function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been told not to use push in my coursework, as we are only allowed to use code we have been taught, which I find ridiculous.

I have written over 200 lines of code incorporating the push function multiple times. Is there a simple code alternative to the push function which I can implement for it?

Comment: You can do `arr[index] = 'something'`

Comment: Or `arr[arr.length] = "something else"`

Comment: The algorithm for *push* is in the language specification ([*§22.1.3.17*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.push)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to push element to the next index in the array, use:

```
var arr = [];
arr[arr.length] = "something";
//output: arr = ["something"]
```

If you need to add element in specific index use:

```
var arr = [];
arr[3] = "something";
//output: arr = [undefined,undefined,undefined,"something"]
```

Comment: A more accurate output is `[,,,"something"]` since the first three members don't exist.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays you can use array destructuring:

```js
let theArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
theArray = [
  ...theArray,
  6,
];
console.log(theArray);
```

If you want to push several elements, put them at the end of the array. You can even put elements at the beginning of the array:

```js
let theArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
theArray = [
  -1,
  0,
  ...theArray,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10
];
console.log(theArray);
```

The doc about it:

[MDN Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Be careful, this reassign the variable with a new array.

Answer (score 5):

The closest equivalent

```
arr[arr.length] = value;
```

Comment: *push* also accepts multiple arguments and increments length (since it's a generic method and works on non–array objects too). It also checks that the lengthened array will have a length < 2^53-1, so it's possible to get a lot closer than that. ;-)

Comment: My answer was based on a hopefully easy search/replace on 200 lines of code - though, 200 lines is warming up really